# Replace a string in the last 100 records on a file using awk

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

So I got around processing the last 100 records of a file declaring a variable using wc -l but I'm having a hard time getting the sub portion of awk to do what I want.

The text below is just an example but it really helps me get the point across the table

```
gold     1    1986  USA                 American Eagle
gold     1    1908  Austria-Hungary     Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver  10    1981  USA                 ingot
gold     1    1984  Switzerland         ingot
gold     1    1979  RSA                 Krugerrand
gold     0.5  1981  RSA                 Krugerrand
gold     0.1  1986  PRC                 Panda
silver   1    1986  USA                 Liberty dollar
gold     0.25 1986  USA                 Liberty 5-dollar piece
```

Let's call this file coins and assume there's over 400 records

```
awk -v v1=$(wc -l < coins) 'NR > v1-100 {gsub /gold/magic/; print}' coins
```

It doesn't really work for me, It'll work if I want to print the first field but I can't seem to get around specifying the number of records and then processing them. I'd like to know how to go on about replacing a string and if needed, printing fields off of the processed text AFTER replacing a string with awk and print the entire file including the records that have been replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
awk -v v1="$(wc -l < coins)" 'NR>(v1-100){gsub(/gold/,"magic")}7' coins
```

this will output 400 lines (say your file has 400lines), but the substitution was done on last 100 lines.

or get the line number by reading the file twice with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{num=NR;next}FNR>(num-100){gsub(/gold/,"magic")}7' coins coins
```

### EDIT

op only wants the last 100 lines in output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{num=NR;next}FNR>(num-100){gsub(/gold/,"magic");print}' coins coins
```

or you can use `tail`:

```
tail -100 coins|awk 'gsub(/gold/,"magic")+7'
```

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick but I have no idea what the number 7 stands for. On a side note, how would you go on about printing out let's say records 1 3 and 5 after substituting the string for either the whole 400 records or the last 100 records? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: @ulisesfierro any non-zero number will do default action `print`. the problem in your codes are: 1) `gsub()` syntax.  2) the `print` should not be in `<100{.... print}` in this way, you only output last 100 lines. so `NR>v1-100{gsub(/gold/,"magic")}7` same as `NR>v1-100{gsub(/gold/,"magic")}{print}`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm still doing something wrong but I have corrected by gsub syntax and the print is not within `<100{.... print}` anymore but I'm still getting the entire file instead of the last 100 records even though the substitution only applies to the last 100 records

Comment: @ulisesfierro I don't understand ... say a file has 400 lines. what do you want to get? only the last 100 lines with replacement job done? or 400 lines, with last 100 lines replaced?

Comment: Only the last 100 lines with the replacement done, I was able to figure out your second option.

Comment: @ulisesfierro then remove the `7` and apply: `{gsub(/gold/,"magic");print}`

Comment: @ulisesfierro I updated answer. added one solution with `tail`

Answer (score 3):

If you have `tac` you can do something like this:

```
tac coins | awk 'NR<=100{gsub(/gold/,"magic")}1' | tac
```

or with `sed`

```
tac coins | sed '1,100s/gold/magic/' | tac
```